# Convert NSString to NSDate and back to different format NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to take the NSString Dec 4, 2012, 12:33 PM and convert it to separate out the month, day, and year, so that I can have 3 different strings of 12, 04, and 2012.

I figure that I should convert the NSString to NSDate and then reformat the date to change out NSString, but am running into issues.

I have:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm p"];
        NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

        dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:substring];
        NSLog(@"Date%@", dateFromString);
        [dateFormatter release];
```

However, the date keeps coming back null.

Comment: can you add the substring assignment?

Comment: @user717452: your substring should be null or it doesn't contain full date..

Comment: The substring is Dec 4, 2012, 12:33 PM

Comment: Take a look at the Apple's `Data Formatting Guide`. It's quite helpful about setting up different formatting:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm p"];
```

to, Because **MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm p**   not a valid date formate

```
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a"];
```

And

```
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:substring];
```

To get string again

```
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
```

for me NSLog is  **Dec 04, 2012, 12:33 PM**

Comment: This works fine, however, when I go to convert the date back to a string and separate components, if the date is a single number, it leaves it as a single number, when I need 04 instead of just 4.

Comment: @user717452 you should also set the locale — device with the non-english locale will fail to parse the string

Comment: I can get it in string, but trying to separate components gives me a problem.  Using what you have, the log shows Dec 04, 2012, 12:33 PM.  I need to separate that out to 12 04 2012 and leave time off, but doing this with components gives me 12 4 2012, and I need the 0 in front.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your locale I think.
You should try to print how your `dateFormatter` formats current date `[NSDate new]`.

It works for me:

```
NSString* substring = @"Dec 12 2012 12:08 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d yyyy h:mm a"]; // not 'p' but 'a'
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:substring];
```

Comment: Your set locale solved my problem to support users of different language. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "NSString+Date.h"

@implementation NSString (Date)

+ (NSDate*)stringDateFromString:(NSString*)string;

{
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
return dateFromString;
}

+(NSString*)StringFromDate :(NSDate*)date;

{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
return stringDate;
 }
```

`     @end